# Unable to load asset, when filename has accent

Tags: flutter

i have a simple `SvgPicture.asset("media/cikkcsoport/$cikkcsoportkod.svg")` in my code,
and if the `$cikkcsoportkod` has accented value, flutter cannot load the asset.

It works with unaccented filenames, only the accented ones drop error messages like:

```
════════ Exception caught by SVG ═══════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown resolving a single-frame picture stream:
Unable to load asset: media/cikkcsoport/AÍ.svg

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.load
package:flutter/…/services/asset_bundle.dart:258
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      AssetBundle.loadString
package:flutter/…/services/asset_bundle.dart:83
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      AssetBundlePictureProvider._loadAsync
package:flutter_svg/src/picture_provider.dart:546
<asynchronous suspension>
Picture provider: ExactAssetPicture(name: "media/cikkcsoport/AÍ.svg", bundle: null, colorFilter: null)
Picture key: AssetBundlePictureKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#17a4a(), name: "media/cikkcsoport/AÍ.svg", colorFilter: null, theme: SvgTheme(currentColor: Color(0xff000000), fontSize: 14.0, xHeight: 7.0))
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by SVG ═══════════════════════════════════════════════
Unable to load asset: media/cikkcsoport/AÓ.svg
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by SVG ═══════════════════════════════════════════════
Unable to load asset: media/cikkcsoport/AÁ.svg
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: I think You should always use small characters with underscores for the asset name, that way you assets can be differentiated and it will stay organized

Comment: Try to add your `pubspec.yaml` file code for assets

Comment: it is in the pubspec.yaml asset section. As i wrote "It works with unaccented filenames".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also created a test project for this issue, but I couldn't reproduce, this problem, because my svg files are renamed differently to the simulator filesystem of my test project.

I couldn't find out, what flutter settings causes the difference in the filename encoding.

Maybe I created my main flutter project from the command line, and the test project from VSCode with the `Flutter: New Project function`.

I can confirm, it is some argument, making the difference, at creating the flutter project.

I created a new flutter project from VSCode, and copy the relevant files to it.

Now I can open all my svg-s.

Answer (score 0):

**Try with the below things.**

- you have latest version on flutter_svg (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg)
- Added asset path in pubspec.yaml
- Flutter clean & Flutter Pub get,

***I hope this things are solve your issue.***

Comment: 1. It is the latest: ```flutter_svg: ^1.1.6```. The svg dir is in the pubspec.yaml asset section. I already tried Flutter clean & Flutter Pub get. It doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: then i think there was some issue in SVG, have you tried to replace that SVG with new or download new SVG..?

Comment: look for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75184232/how-can-i-use-accented-asset-file-names-in-flutter-update-where-can-i-change-m Flutter somehow, not using the right filename encoding.