# how can I use accented asset file names in flutter? UPDATE: Where can I change my flutter project filename encoding?

Tags: flutter

According to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75146761/unable-to-load-asset-when-filename-has-accent), I figured out, on my m1 mac mini, flutter changes the accented svg assets filename, when it builds the android or ios image.

For example these files,

```
AA.svg
AÓ.svg
AÍ.svg
```

are renamed to

```
AA.svg
AO%CC%81.svg
AI%CC%81.svg
```

How can I open these renamed files in flutter with the `SvgPicture.asset()` function?

I tried to open as `AÓ.svg`, and another way, directly open the accented files as `SvgPicture.asset("media/cikkcsoport/AO%CC%81.svg")`, and I still get  the `Unable to load asset: media/cikkcsoport/AO%CC%81.svg` error message.

**UPDATE**

I created a test project, and I use the same svg files as in my main.
In the test project, the accented svg's also work.
When I check the simulator filesystem, I see, flutter use a different filename encoding in this project.

For example, I get these files:

```
A%C3%81.svg
A%C3%8D.svg
A%C3%93.svg
```

Where can I change my flutter project filename encoding?

Comment: why don't you simply rename the files to not have accented letters?

Comment: Because, i get this filenames from a server, so I cannot change them.

Comment: but they're assets in your projects assets folder aren't they? So they are only read once when you build the app...so surely you could choose to rename them before you build the app??

Comment: Yes, I can rename the files, but then I need to alter the content, what I get from the server, to match the renamed files. This can be a workaround, but not the solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find out, what flutter settings causes the difference in the filename encoding.

Maybe I created my main flutter project from the command line, and the test project from VSCode with the `Flutter: New Project function`.

I can confirm, it is some argument, making the difference, at creating the flutter project.

I created a new flutter project from VSCode, and copy the relevant files to it.

Now I can open all my svg-s.

Answer (score 0):

That has nothing to do with flutter, the urls are encoded that way, so you just need to use `Uri.decodeFull()` from the [`Uri class`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.7/dart-core/Uri-class.html) to get a valid string.

```dart
final base_name = 'media/cikkcsoport/AÓ.svg';
final encoded_name = Uri.encodeFull(base_name);   
final decoded_name = Uri.decodeFull(encoded_name); 
print('($base_name) $encoded_name -> $decoded_name');
```

Comment: This is not the problem. Your code gives me: ```flutter: (media/cikkcsoport/AÓ.svg) media/cikkcsoport/A%C3%93.svg -> media/cikkcsoport/AÓ.svg```, but in my simulator filesystem, I have ```AO%CC%81.svg``` filename. I don't know why, but when flutter creates the image, in my main project, it renames the accented svg files differently, than in my test project, where the filename is ```A%C3%93.svg```, and flutter can find it.

Comment: I gave you an example with how `Ó` is transformed into `O%CC%81`, what did you expect the code todo; that aside, if you are able to print `Ó` from your code that means that the encoding of the file is not the problem.

Comment: I don't understand. What is the solution then? I try to load the images with ```SvgPicture.asset()```. In my test project, I can do it like this: ```SvgPicture.asset("media/cikkcsoport/AÓ.svg")```. In my main project I cannot load the file this way, also cannot load this way: ```SvgPicture.asset(Uri.decodeFull("media/cikkcsoport/AÓ.svg"))```

Comment: With ```SvgPicture.asset(Uri.decodeFull(```, I get ```Invalid argument(s): Illegal percent encoding in URI```, so this is not the String format, what ```SvgPicture.asset``` expects.

Comment: I am pretty sure, the filename is the problem. Even ```Uri.encodeFull``` gives ```A%C3%93.svg```, not ```AO%CC%81.svg```, what I have at filesystem level. In my test project, the filename is ```A%C3%93.svg```, and flutter can open it.

Comment: Use the encode to create a url compatible string, and the decode to get the original string, in the link from the post you can find this [see also](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/library-tour#uris); even if it's an asset it need to match simple characters from the utf8 and the dash lines (more or less) becase they are actual urls but you just use the path.

Comment: I already have the valid UTF-8 string originally. Don't need to decode it.

Comment: Then find that character in the [utf8 table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Codepage_layout).